# 404 error in Spring (java config / no web.xml)

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config, custom-error-pages

Trying to provide a custom 404 error page in a web application that, to the best of my knowledge, uses Java Config (thus no web.xml).

We have the following versions of the related libraries: spring ("5.1.2.RELEASE"), spring-security ("5.1.1.RELEASE").

### Disclaimer

> I have checked different approaches here in StackOverflow. Please
>   don't suggest results for web.xml, Thymeleaf or Spring Boot. This is
>   not applicable.

Among others; I tried with the following approaches:

- `@Controller` annotation ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398385/spring-boot-and-custom-404-error-page) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396100/spring-security-how-to-intercept-pagenotfound))
- adding a web.xml

None produced the expected result (that is, still getting the default webserver layout and error).

#### Controller annotation approach

- exception package

  ```
  package ...;

  import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
  import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;

  @ControllerAdvice
  public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

      // Option A (used as an alternative to option B)
      //@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
      //public String handle(Exception ex) {
      //   return "redirect:/404";
      //}

      @RequestMapping(value = {"/404"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String NotFoundPage() {
          return "404";
      }

      // Option B (used as an alternative to option A)
      @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
      public ResponseEntity<String> handleNoHandlerFoundException(GlobalExceptionHandler ex) {
          ResponseEntity responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(new RestClientException("Testing exception"),
              HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
          return responseEntity;
      }
  }
  ```
- init class

  ```
  package ...;

  import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
  import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
  import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
  import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;

  @Configuration
  @ComponentScan("...")
  @EnableWebMvc
  @EnableTransactionManagement
  @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
  public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

      @ExceptionHandler({ Exception.class })
      public ResponseEntity<RestClientException> handle(NoHandlerFoundException e) {
          return new ResponseEntity<>(new RestClientException("Testing exception"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
      }

      ...

      @Override
      public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
          super.addViewControllers(registry);
          registry.addViewController("/404.jsp").setViewName("404");
      }
  }
  ```

There is also an `Initializer` class (`public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer`), which seems to conflict with some suggested options (defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34973476/2186237) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31436535/2186237)); so the webapp-init class is not modified.

#### web.xml approach

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="ROOT" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>

</web-app>
```

The `404.jsp` or `404.html` files are placed (currently for testing purposes at all the following locations):

```
    src/main/resources
    ├── ...
    ├── error
    │   └── 404.html
    ├── public
    │   ├── 404.html
    │   └── error
    │       └── 404.html
    ├── templates
    │   └── 404.html
    └── ...

    src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/
    ├── error.jsp
    ├── tags
    │   └── ...
    └── views
        ├── 404.html
        ├── 404.jsp
        ├── error.jsp
        └── ...
```

Any idea on what is missing or wrong?

Comment: probably already has an answer on stackOverflow, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398385/spring-boot-and-custom-404-error-page

Comment: I don't think so. You point to something with Spring-Boot or Thymeleaf. That is not my case. I added some references of suggestions like these which did not work for me.

Comment: Try to follow same folder structure. As said in there "If you want to display a custom HTML error page for a given status code, you add a file to an /error folder." I don't try to be cleaver, just do something that works and later customize for your needs. simple

Comment: I have just tried with the same structure (under `src/main/resources/public/error/`); yet no luck

Comment: Find where they mention ErrorController, as I understood you can extend that with custom error path, or do logic as they did. I would put breakpoints in BasicErrorController and AbstractErrorController everywhere and see what the flow is.

Comment: Hmm, sorry... I fail to see how that can help. First, that is for Spring Boot so ErrorController cannot be imported. Second, even if it was, for normal Spring that's a normal `@RequestMapping` directive which is not used as fallback for error handling but only for explicit redirection (`return /error` and the like). What I want to do is to provide a default handler for 404 (and these cannot be redirected from the normal Controller classes, afaik)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not as clear as I would like, this is a sort of working version to at least provide some customisation to error pages. It is a first approach but hopefully can help others.

The list of handled exceptions is not extensive, but mainly addressing 404 errors (`NoHandlerFoundException`) and other *typical* errors like `InternalServerErrorException` and `NullPointerException`, to try to catch them all in the end with a generic error for everything else that is an `Exception`).

***Note*** that this is not covering other exceptions related to e.g. bad syntax in a JSTL template (`org.apache.jasper.*`; exceptions that cannot apparently be caught here).

These are the related changes and additions to the source base:

**CustomSimpleMappingExceptionResolver.java** (provide generic exceptions, yet logs details)

```
package ...;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;

public class CustomSimpleMappingExceptionResolver extends SimpleMappingExceptionResolver {

    public CustomSimpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
        // Turn logging on by default
        setWarnLogCategory(getClass().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public String buildLogMessage(Exception e, HttpServletRequest req) {
        return "MVC exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView doResolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                              Object handler, Exception ex) {

        // Log exception
        ex.printStackTrace();
        String exceptionCause = ex.toString();
        String exceptionType = ex.getClass().getCanonicalName();

        // Get the ModelAndView to use
        ModelAndView mav = super.doResolveException(request, response, handler, ex);

        // Make more information available to the view - note that SimpleMappingExceptionResolver adds the exception already
        mav.addObject("url", request.getRequestURL());
        mav.addObject("timestamp", new Date());

        ArrayList<String> exceptions404 = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(
                        NoHandlerFoundException.class.getName()
                        )
        );
        ArrayList<String> exceptions500 = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(
                        InternalServerErrorException.class.getName(),
                        NullPointerException.class.getName()
                        )
        );

        String userExceptionDetail = ex.toString();
        String errorHuman = "";
        String errorTech = "";

        if (exceptions404.contains(exceptionType)) {
            errorHuman = "We cannot find the page you are looking for";
            errorTech = "Page not found";
            userExceptionDetail = String.format("The page %s cannot be found", request.getRequestURL());
            mav.setViewName("/error/404");
            mav.addObject("status", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        } else if (exceptions500.contains(exceptionType)) {
            errorHuman = "We cannot currently serve the page you request";
            errorTech = "Internal error";
            userExceptionDetail = "The current page refuses to load due to an internal error";
            mav.setViewName("/error/500");
            mav.addObject("status", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        } else {
            errorHuman = "We cannot serve the current page";
            errorTech = "General error";
            userExceptionDetail = "A generic error prevents from serving the page";
            mav.setViewName("/error/generic");
            mav.addObject("status", response.getStatus());
        }

        Exception userException = new Exception(userExceptionDetail);
        mav.addObject("error_human", errorHuman);
        mav.addObject("error_tech", errorTech);
        mav.addObject("exception", userException);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

**WebAppConfig.java** (registers custom exception resolver as an exception handler)

```
package ...;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
import java.lang.NullPointerException;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("...")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    // ...

    @Bean
    HandlerExceptionResolver customExceptionResolver () {
        CustomSimpleMappingExceptionResolver resolver = new CustomSimpleMappingExceptionResolver();
        Properties mappings = new Properties();
        // Mapping Spring internal error NoHandlerFoundException to a view name
        mappings.setProperty(NoHandlerFoundException.class.getName(), "/error/404");
        mappings.setProperty(InternalServerErrorException.class.getName(), "/error/500");
        mappings.setProperty(NullPointerException.class.getName(), "/error/500");
        mappings.setProperty(ClassNotFoundException.class.getName(), "/error/500");
        mappings.setProperty(Exception.class.getName(), "/error/generic");
        resolver.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
        // Set specific HTTP codes
        resolver.addStatusCode("404", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        resolver.addStatusCode("500", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        resolver.setDefaultErrorView("/error/generic");
        resolver.setDefaultStatusCode(200);
        // This resolver will be processed before the default ones
        resolver.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        resolver.setExceptionAttribute("exception");
        return resolver;
    }

    // ...

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
    }
}
```

**Initializer.java** (adding `dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);`; maybe not needed)

```
package ...;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(ctx);
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);

        // Add the dispatcher servlet mapping manually and make it initialize automatically
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", dispatcherServlet);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.addMapping("*.png");
        servlet.addMapping("*.jpg");
        servlet.addMapping("*.css");
        servlet.addMapping("*.js");
        servlet.addMapping("*.txt");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        // ...

    }
}
```

Structure of views and tags related to error classes:

```
    src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/
    ├── tags
    │   └── error.tag
    └── views
        ├── error
        │   ├── 404.jsp
        │   ├── 500.jsp
        └────── generic.jsp
```

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/error.tag**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Error page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h3><c:out value="${error_human}" /></h3>

    <p><br/><br/></p>

    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <c:out value="${error_tech}" />
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p><c:out value="${exception_message}" /></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/error/404.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
         pageEncoding="utf-8" isErrorPage="true" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/" prefix="g" %>

<c:set var = "error_human" scope = "session" value = "We cannot find the page you are looking for"/>
<c:set var = "error_tech" scope = "session" value = "Page not found"/>
<c:set var = "exception_message" scope = "session" value = "The current page cannot be found"/>
<g:error />
```

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/error/500.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
         pageEncoding="utf-8" isErrorPage="true" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/" prefix="g" %>

<c:set var = "error_human" scope = "session" value = "We cannot currently serve the page you request"/>
<c:set var = "error_tech" scope = "session" value = "Internal error"/>
<c:set var = "exception_message" scope = "session" value = "The current page refuses to load due to an internal error"/>
<g:error />
```

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/error/generic.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
         pageEncoding="utf-8" isErrorPage="true" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/" prefix="g" %>

<c:set var = "error_human" scope = "session" value = "We cannot serve the current page"/>
<c:set var = "error_tech" scope = "session" value = "General error"/>
<c:set var = "exception_message" scope = "session" value = "A generic error prevents from serving the page"/>
<g:error />
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Spring Boot docs, this works for me:

```
  @Bean
   public ErrorPageRegistrar errorPageRegistrar() {
     return registry -> registry.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/index.html"));  }
```

This is equivalente to web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can access 404 page, and then add these codes.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String handle404(Model model, HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
        return "/404";
    }
}
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  mvc:
    throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound: true # if page not found, it will throw error, and then ControllerAdvice will catch the error.
```

PS: springBoot version=2.4.2; Java=15